# Why is hashCode() called once in case of iterating through one bucket with multiply values?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I've got a following class

```
public class Animal {

    private int hash;

    public Animal(int hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        System.out.println(hash);
        return hash;
    }
}
```

And this code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Animal, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            map.put(new Animal(16 * i), i);
        }

        Animal an = new Animal(16*4);
        map.put(an, 1);

        for (int i = 5; i < 9; i++) {
            map.put(new Animal(16 * i), i);
        }
        Integer value = map.get(an);
    }
```

As I understand, all this values should be in one single bucket (due to their hashcodes). At the last call `map.get(an)`, hashCode() is called only once (according to console), but should not it be called several times while iteration through bucket and finding an entry with the right hashCode() ?

EDIT1: If I implement `equals` (with console logging), it is not called either (according to console again), it is only called when there are two objects with the **same** hashcode (if for example I add this to my code `map.put(new Animal(16*3), 4);`, and in this case hashCode() is called **twice** when getting an object from map).

Comment: Note that you didn't implement `equals`.

Comment: Why do you think they should all be in the same bucket? The `Animal` instances you create have mostly different hashCode values, why should they have hash collisions?

Comment: Apart from that: `HashMap` caches the hash code of the keys it stores, so it will only ever need to call `hashCode` on its keys once when they are added.

Comment: @JoachimSauer index_of_bucket= hashCode(key) & (n-1), my hashCodes are 0, 16, 32 ... and n (size of map) by default is 16

Comment: @BogdanTimofeev: that's not how the Java `HashMap` uses the hash, it actually manipulates it before using it. Check the private `HashMap.hash(Object)` method in your favorite JVM implementation.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it works like this
(key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
but for 0, 16, 32, .. hashcodes it returns the same value (0, 16, 32, ..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single bucket may contain keys having different `hashCode`, and the `hashCode` of the keys of the relevant bucket is compared to the key you are adding/searching for. However, the `hashCode` is cached in the `Map.Entry`, so there's no need to call the key's `hashCode` method for `Entry`s that are already in the `Map`:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next;

    Node(int hash, K key, V value, Node<K,V> next) {
        this.hash = hash; // here the hash code is cached
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
    ...
}
```

That's an implementation detail, though.

You can see here the code used to locate an `Entry` for a given `hash` and `key`:

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // <--- here a cached hash is compared to hash
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&  // <--- here a cached hash is compared to hash
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

`hash` is compared to the cached `hash` values of the keys, which means there's no need to call `hashCode()` again.

Answer (score 2):

No, the hashcode is used to find the bucket, which requires a single call to `hashcode` (called on the argument of `map.get(an)`).

The  elements in the bucket are then compared with `equals()` to find the correct object.

Comment: equals is not called also (see my edit 1), looks like there is no collision at all

Comment: @BogdanTimofeev well it's not called if it's not necessary. Is this question about collisions or about when `equals()` and `hashCode()` is used?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone already answers the question already. I would like to capture the code from HashMap to provide more information

When we call .put from Map, internally they call hashKey first
[image: .put]

In-side the hash() method, you will see hashCode() is called.

[image: hash() method]

And then in the putVal method, there are couple places equals get called as below
[image: putValue() method]

That is why we will get several times hashCode() get called.

Please check this link https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java for the implementation of HashMap if you need to understand more

Answer (score 0):

At most you can expect `hashCode()` to be called at all. The number of invocations is an implementation detail to `HashMap` and you should not expect any specific behavior, nor that an observed behavior is stable. As `hashCode()` could be implemented differently, even costly, it is a reasonable choice to call it only once and even if it is needed multiple times go with the returned value instead new calls to `hashCode()`. Yet this is not more than a guess and should not be assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Once the bucket is determined, `HashMap` will use .`eqauls` to determined the linked-list node that matches the supplied object. See the implementation:

```
/**
 * Implements Map.get and related methods
 *
 * @param hash hash for key
 * @param key the key
 * @return the node, or null if none
 */
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map.put(new Animal(16 * i), i);`

when you do this, the `Animal` object is key and its hash value will be the bucket which the value `i`. Think of it as Animal object is not even stored in map.

when you add all the 9 items, the buckets having values are 0,16,32,48,...,(16*8)

when you do `map.get(aa)`, so hash of `an` is returned from `an` object which is 64.

tl;dr all the objects belong to different buckets (because their hashValues are different)